# Understanding interface definition from C# book

Tags: c#, interface

I'm currently studying the Inheritance chapter of a C# book. I'm unable to understand the following line.

> **Interfaces enable you to separate the definition of objects from their implementation so that the objects can evolve without the risk
>   of introducing incompatibility in existing applications.**

Could anyone help me to understand what that line of text is saying with an example?

Comment: this question might help you clear up things a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1335586/13198

Comment: May I also know what does "definition of objects" in above line?

Comment: Thanks to all for their time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Interfaces enable you to separate the definition of objects from 
their implementation
```

Definition of objects in this case refers to the publicly exposed part of an object.
In the example below, it refers to the public properties `Name / Age` and the Public methods `Insert` and `Update`.
In the below class, the definition of Person and its implementation (code used to implement the properties and methods) is the same i.e  the class Person.

```
Class Person 
{
  private string _name; //private fields
  private string _age;  //private fields

  public Name {get {....} set {.....}}  //public properties
  public Age {get {....} set {.....}}  //public properties

  public void Insert() {.......} //public methods
  public void Update() {.......} //public methods
}
```

NOTE: "........" represents actual code which will be called when these properties / methods are invoked i.e their implementation.

Now, if i were to do create an interface for this called

```
Interface IPerson 
{
  public Name get; set;  //public properties
  public Age get; set;   //public properties
  public void Insert(); //public methods
  public void Update(); //public methods
}
```

and then do `Class Person : IPerson`
then what I have done is that i have now separated the DEFINITION i.e. `IPerson` from the Implementation i.e `Person`.

**NOTE : Why this is useful is already covered by Aamir and Gravell in their answers above so i wont repeat the same**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure I'd entirely *agree* with the line - after all, you can *still* put a bug in the implementation - but the point is abstraction; if all you know about is that `IAnimal` has a `Speak()` method, you don't need to know about `Dog`, `Cat`, etc; and you don't need to know when somebody swaps `Dog` for `DogFacade`, `LazyLoadedDog`, etc. As long as the thing they give you is an `IAnimal`, you'll be happy - and won't need to change the downstream code.

(and if the `Dog` class wants to expose a `Bark()` method instead, then that is fine; it can have `Speak` as an *explicit implementation* of `IAnimal.Speak`)

Answer (score 0):

This means that Interfaces allow you to define the basic functions of a set of things. How they are going to perform those functions is left to the things themselves. For example, a human can walk but how a male, female, old person, child etc walks is different but we can say that they all walk.

So, an interface is a group of functions put together which can be implemented differently by different classes.