# Interfaces, properties and reflection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, interface

Does anyone know a way of obtaining the underlying property name for an interface property?

For example, take [Juliet's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558152/asp-net-unfamiliar-with-interfaces) excellent example of interfaces which I've modified slightly:

```
Module1

Interface ILifeform 
    ReadOnly Property Name() As String 
    Sub Speak() 
    Sub Eat() 
End Interface 

Class Dog 
    Implements ILifeform 

    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String Implements ILifeform.Name 
        Get 
            Return "Doggy!" 
        End Get 
    End Property 

    Public Sub Talk() Implements ILifeform.Speak 
        Console.WriteLine("Woof!") 
    End Sub 

    Public Sub Eat() Implements ILifeform.Eat 
        Console.WriteLine("Yum, doggy biscuits!") 
    End Sub 
End Class 

Class Ninja 
    Implements ILifeform 

    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String Implements ILifeform.Name 
        Get 
            Return "Ninja!!" 
        End Get 
    End Property 

    Public Sub Speak() Implements ILifeform.Speak 
        Console.WriteLine("Ninjas are silent, deadly killers") 
    End Sub 

    Public Sub Eat() Implements ILifeform.Eat 
        Console.WriteLine("Ninjas don't eat, they wail on guitars and kick ass") 
    End Sub 
End Class 

Class Monkey 
    Implements ILifeform 


    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String Implements ILifeform.Name 
        Get 
            Return "Monkey!!!" 
        End Get 
    End Property 

    Public Sub Speak() Implements ILifeform.Speak 
        Console.WriteLine("Ook ook") 
    End Sub 

    Public Sub Eat() Implements ILifeform.Eat 
        Console.WriteLine("Bananas!") 
    End Sub 
End Class 


Sub Main() 
    Dim lifeforms As ILifeform() = New ILifeform() {New Dog(), New Ninja(), New Monkey()} 
    For Each x As ILifeform In lifeforms 
        HandleLifeform(x) 
    Next 

    Console.ReadKey(True) 
End Sub 

Sub HandleLifeform(ByVal x As ILifeform) 
    Console.WriteLine("Handling lifeform '{0}'", x.Name) 
    x.Speak() 
    x.Eat() 
    Console.WriteLine() 
End Sub 
End Module
```

For the Dog class, the property implementing 'Speak' is called 'Talk'.

If I received a dog object as an 'object' type could I do something like this?

```
If TypeOf(object) Is ILifeForm Then
   Dim str as string = CType(object, ILifeForm).GetUnderLyingPropertyName("Speak"))
   ' str now contains "Talk"
End If
```

Comment: Why would you name the method implementing your interface method something else? That's just bad from a design standpoint.

Comment: @Tejs I didn't even realize vb.net would allow this to happen...

Comment: Yeah, I didnt either. Currently reading about that. I think it stems from them being able to determine an implict of explicit interface implementation as compared to C#

Comment: Either way, @Trucker_Jim, interfaces are probably not what you want if your trying to do something like this. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to mitigate for the fact that an underlying property name doesn't have to mirror the interface property name. I've created an IMailMergeable interface with a propety called TextToMerge. When an object is given to my web control it populates its control labels using the display names of the properties. If the object is IMailMergable a list of the merge fields appears and asks the user to highlight and drag them to a TextToMerge field on the page. But, the TextToMerge property might be called 'Message' so that would confuse the user.

Answer (score -2):

why doing this:

```
CType(object, ILifeForm).GetUnderLyingPropertyName("Speak"))
```

when it is much simpler doing this:

```
CType(object, ILifeForm).Speak
```

?
Job Done. that's a classic polymorphism.

Comment: You didn't understand the question.